# What is the solution of $(u')^2=\frac{1}{1+u^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to parametrise a parabola $(u,\frac{u^2}{2})$ by arclength, I came up with the following differential equation: $$(u')^2=\frac{1}{1+u^2}$$

I tryed with some function from (hyperbolic) trigonometry but did not found the solution. I think it should be something very very classic.

Comment: not seeing a great closed-form solution using Wolfram Alpha although it can solve for the inverse function of $u$. Any context on where this is showing up?

Comment: By the power on $u'$ do you mean $u'$ squared or the second derivative ?

Comment: @Filthyscrub $u'$ squared

Comment: Use the trig substitution $u=\tan \theta$

Comment: @hunter trying to parametrise a parabola $(u,\frac{u^2}{2})$ by arclength :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $u=u(x)$, $u'= \frac{du}{dx}$.
$$
\frac{du}{dx}\large = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}
$$
$$
\implies\int\large(\sqrt{1+u^2}\large)du = \pm \int dx 
$$
$$
\implies \frac{u\sqrt{1+u^2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(u+\sqrt{1+u^2}) = \pm x + C.
$$

Left integral is known: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ssJcTQRmNU&ab_channel=IntegralsForYou

Comment: so, no "famous" closed form for that, right?

Comment: @user126154 I do not know if there is :(

Answer (score 2):

If you set $u=\sinh(v)$ you get $1+u^2=\cosh^2(v)$ and the equation becomes
$$
\cosh^4(v)(v')^2=1\implies (1+\cosh(2v))v'=\pm2\implies 2v+\sinh(2v)=\pm4x+C
$$
which now is a very implicit solution.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail for the calculation? I like this approach to the answer, but some of the steps are not obvious to me.

Comment: To make $1+u^2$ a square without losing generality, you can use $u=\sinh(v)$ or $u=\tan(v)$. Similarly for $1-u^2$ one would use $u=\sin v$,... Sometimes this works, often not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems easier (at least to me) to switch variables and write
$$(x')^2=1+u^2$$ and get immediately
$$x+C= \pm \frac{1}{2} \left(u\sqrt{u^2+1} +\sinh ^{-1}(u)\right)$$ which cannot be inversed.